# navigation: setOnClickListener(this) jump to onClick

Tags: java, eclipse, android-studio, intellij-idea, netbeans

**Please, if you don't know how to do it in Android Studio / IntelliJ idea, but know how it's called in any other IDE - tell me about it. Thank you!**

It seems I want some navigation shortcut that allows me to jump to (or to show if there're plenty of them) the interface implementation method.

For instance, there's a code:

```
class Activity implements OnClickListener {

    Activity(){
        button1.setOnClickListener(this); // this should implement OnClickListener
        button2.setOnClickListener(this);
    }

    // 1M lines of code :)

    @Override
    public void onClick(View v){
        ...
    }

}
```

So, when I want to jump in `onClick` method when I click in IDE by `this`. Hope, you got my question well.

Thank you in advance! :)

Comment: What have you written so far for this? What did that give you? What errors are you getting (if any)?

Comment: Sorry, didn't get you. Could you, please, restate?

Comment: I meant, Have you tried coding whatever you wanted? If you have, what was the error you found?

Comment: Hm. I'm not discussing any error right now :) I'm just asking about an IDE feature. Do you understand my question or should I restate it somehow?